# Router link not calling router view on nested routes

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I have a router

```
routes: [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    meta : {
      label : 'Home'
    },
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/usuarios',
    name: 'usuarios',
    meta : {
      label : 'Usuarios'
    },
    component: Users,
    children :  [
      {
        path: '/listar',
        meta : {
          label : 'Listar'
        },
        name      : 'listUser',
        component: Wrapper,
      },
      {
        path: '/cadastrar',
        meta : {
          label : 'Cadastrar !'
        },
        name      : 'userCreate',
        component: UserCreate
      },
    ],

  },

]
```

And I have a template for rendering this router at my navbar

```
<div class="main">

  <ul class="menu-list">
    <li v-for="item in menus" v-on:click="toggleActive(item)">
      <router-link class="font-gray" :to="item.path" :exact="true">{{item.meta.label}}</router-link>
      <ul class="menu-list" v-if="item.children && item.isActive">
        <li v-for="child in item.children">
          <router-link class="font-gray" :to="{path : item.path+child.path}" :exact="true" :append="true" >{{child.meta.label}}</router-link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When I click on the first router-link, the view is rendered with no problem at the router view. But when I click on the router link of childrens, it does not work,

Anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Is it because you are using `append`? What do you mean "it doesn't work"?

Comment: Sorry, I was just making some tests with this append. With or without it, it still not working. I mean it does not render the component on the <router-view> tag

Comment: You click the link and nothing happens? No errors in the console?

Comment: No errors, the only thing is when I look at the vue dev tools, the  router-view component is not there. No errors, no warnings

Comment: Try `:to="{ name: child.name }"`

Comment: Are you trying to implement a dropdown?

Comment: I tried with :to="{ name: child.name }", and still the same. Yes, I am trying to implement a dropdown

Comment: What is the text that results if you put `{{ item.path+child.path }}` directly after the `router-link` tag?

Comment: Also, why are you using `:exact`? That seems like it could be causing problems.

Comment: the :exact is for matching navbar item with the url. The result with item.path+child.path, is the route, like /usuario/cadastrar

Comment: Is it exactly `/usuario/cadastrar`? Not `/usuarios/cadastrar`? Because that path isn't defined in your routes

Comment: Sorry, /usuarios/cadastrar. I tried defining the children path as /usuarios/cadastrar, instead of /cadastrar, but not work too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144951/discussion-between-thanksd-and-victor-oliveira).

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured it out.

If you have children, the father component should have a `<router-view>` as well

Found the answer here: [Vue router2 not catching deep nested routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41590297/vue-router2-not-catching-deep-nested-routes)

Thanks everybody for trying help

Answer (score 0):

This issue is happening because you have forward slashes `/` prepended to the paths of your nested routes.

From the [documentation on nested routes](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/nested-routes.html):

> Note that nested paths that start with / will be treated as a root path. This allows you to leverage the component nesting without having to use a nested URL.

This means that, even though your `"listar"` route is a child of your `"usuarios"` route, the path is `/listar`, not `/usuarios/listar`.

You should remove the forward slashes from the paths of your nested routes, and then specify the path in your template like so:

```
:to="{ path : item.path + '/' + child.path }"
```

Comment: I removed the forward slash, and let only the "listar" and still not working. But now the router view still visible on the vue dev tools